# How can I create a vector layer in PyQGIS from a table without geom column?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS I've got a Spatialite database containing tables without a geometry column. With the QGIS GUI it is perfectly possible to add such a table as a 'Spatialite vector layer'.
But how to do this in Python?

On the console I've tried:

```
>>> uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
>>> uri.setDatabase('/<path>/test.sqlite')
>>> uri.setDataSource('', 'TestTableName','','','id')
>>> vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'TestLayer', 'spatialite')
>>> QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

No result

```
>>> vlayer.isValid()
False
```

What is going wrong?

Some extra analysis:
When I add this layer by the GUI the uri-description is as follows:

```
>>> qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'dbname=\'/<path>/test.sqlite\' table="TestTableName" sql=')
```

When I add this layer by the Python console as described above, the uri-description is somewhat different:

```
>>> uri.uri()
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'dbname=\'/<path>/test.sqlite\' table="TestTableName" () sql=')
```

Could the empty parentheses cause the different behaviour? So maybe QGIS 1.8.0 handles empty parentheses different as no parentheses?

Comment: The exact code you posted works perfectly here (with QGIS 1.9)

Comment: @gene. Hmm, weird. I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 on OS X. It only works for me when I use a table with a geometry column, so something must go wrong in line:
`>>> uri.setDataSource('',<table_name>,'')`
As adding this layer with the GUI works fine, maybe QGIS is using different code for non geometry tables?

Comment: The parentheses in the uri cause the problem. I've solved it as follows: uri2 = QgsDataSourceURI(uri.uri().remove(' ()')) vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri2.uri(), 'TestLayer', 'spatialite') vlayer.isValid() True It looks like this problem does not occur in QGIS 1.9. Same issue ( and same solution -> thanks a lot Spingerfitz) with postgres and QGIS 2.12

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85657)

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I got it working. My analysis seems right. The parentheses in the uri cause the problem. I've solved it as follows:

```
>>> uri2 = QgsDataSourceURI(uri.uri().remove(' ()'))
>>> vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri2.uri(), 'TestLayer', 'spatialite')
>>> vlayer.isValid()
True
```

It looks like this problem does not occur in QGIS 1.9 >.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing

With a SQLite layer (not spatial)

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setDatabase('Midv_31370.sqlite')
uri.setDataSource('', 'obs_points','','','obsid')
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'TestLayer2', 'spatialite')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
vlayer.isValid()
True
```

[image]

If you want a spatial layer (Spatialite), you must indicate the geometry column:

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setDatabase('Midv_31370.sqlite')
uri.setDataSource('', 'obs_points', 'geometry')
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'TestLayer2', 'spatialite')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
vlayer.isValid()
True
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, weird. I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 on OS X. It only works for me when I use a table with a geometry column, so something must go wrong in line:
    >>> uri.setDataSource('',<table_name>,'')